# Kubernetes split-brain / HA across AZ

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-health-check

The [Kubernetes HA documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/) shows that you can ensure availability in the case of the failure of an apiserver by having multiple instances behind a load balancer.

However, it doesn't cover what happens if the Kubernetes is deployed across multiple availability zones.  There is [some documentation here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/multiple-zones/) but it doesn't really go into failure scenarios.

What is best practice here?  Should you pin the api-servers to instances inside each AZ?  What happens in the event of a split brain?  If I have a pod running in one AZ and it becomes unavailable to the rest of the world, what happens to it?

I specifically want to know about a custom on-premise installation, not AWS or GCE.

Comment: You can also have a look at k8s [federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/federation/) to manage multiple independently connected clusters across zones.

Comment: Have a look at the [kops HA documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/high_availability.md). kops is a tool for operating k8s in AWS, which I know is not what you are looking for. Still, their documentation further highlights, that k8s state is stored in etcd. So k8s and etcd are likely to have very similar HA rules/approaches.